# Помогите исправить мою ошибку

Tags: python, aiogram

Вот мой код:

```
import logging
from typing import Text
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, executor, types
from requests.api import get
import config
import requests
import json
from aiogram.dispatcher.filters import Text

def get_bitcoin_price() -> int:
    # Делаем запрос на получение цены биткоина
    response = requests.get('https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/simple/price?ids=bitcoin&vs_currencies=usd').text
    bitcoinjson = json.loads(response)
    return int(bitcoinjson["bitcoin"]["usd"])


# Объект бота
bot = Bot(config.token)

# Диспетчер для бота
dp = Dispatcher(bot)

# Включаем логирование, чтобы не пропустить важные сообщения
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)

# Хэндлер на команду /price
@dp.message_handler(commands=["price"])
async def priceb(message: types.Message):
    await message.answer(f"Цена биткоина = {get_bitcoin_price()}")

@dp.message_handler(commands=["alert"])   
async def alarm(message: types.Message):
    mean = int(message.text[6:])
    n = False
    while n == False:
        if mean < get_bitcoin_price():
            await message.answer(f"Цена биткоина пересекла вашу отметку {mean}")
            n = True

        
    


if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Запуск бота
    executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)
```

а вот ошибка, возникающая после вызова команды /alert

```
ERROR:asyncio:Task exception was never retrieved
future: <Task finished name='Task-12' coro=<Dispatcher._process_polling_updates() done, defined at C:\Users\Vladimir\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\dispatcher.py:409> exception=JSONDecodeError('Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)')>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Vladimir\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\dispatcher.py", line 417, in _process_polling_updates
    for responses in itertools.chain.from_iterable(await self.process_updates(updates, fast)):
  File "C:\Users\Vladimir\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\dispatcher.py", line 238, in process_updates
    return await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
  File "C:\Users\Vladimir\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\handler.py", line 116, in notify
    response = await handler_obj.handler(*args, **partial_data)
  File "C:\Users\Vladimir\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\dispatcher.py", line 259, in process_update
    return await self.message_handlers.notify(update.message)
  File "C:\Users\Vladimir\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\handler.py", line 116, in notify
    response = await handler_obj.handler(*args, **partial_data)
  File "c:\Users\Vladimir\Desktop\telegrambitcoinbot\bot.py", line 36, in alarm
    if mean < get_bitcoin_price():
  File "c:\Users\Vladimir\Desktop\telegrambitcoinbot\bot.py", line 13, in get_bitcoin_price
    bitcoinjson = json.loads(response)
  File "C:\Users\Vladimir\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\json\__init__.py", line 346, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Users\Vladimir\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\json\decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Users\Vladimir\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\json\decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Comment: Ошибку не решают, её совершают!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ошибка скорее всего из-за того, что поступает слишком много запросов от вашего компьютера на сервер, и он выдает ошибку. Думаю, нужно поставить задержку перед каждым опросом сервера.

И совмещать асинхронные функции с синхронными не есть хорошей практикой. Плюс лучше заменить `requests` на `aiohttp`:

`pip install aiohttp`

Привел ниже код, но ваша концепция проверки, пересекла ли цена биткоина которую задали - ужасная. Например произошел сбой бота, вы его перезапустили, а цена нигде не сохранилась и придется юзеру вводить ее заново - это уже вам задача на раздумья и реализацию:)

Цену, которую задали - можно записывать к примеру в базу данных.

Ваш подправленный код:

```
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, executor, types
from aiogram.dispatcher.filters import Text
from requests.api import get
from typing import Text
import asyncio
import logging
import aiohttp
import config


async def get_bitcoin_price():
    # Делаем запрос на получение цены биткоина
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        async with session.get('https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/simple/price?ids=bitcoin&vs_currencies=usd') as response:
            bitcoin = await response.json()
        return int(bitcoin["bitcoin"]["usd"])


# Объект бота
bot = Bot(config.token)

# Диспетчер для бота
dp = Dispatcher(bot)

# Включаем логирование, чтобы не пропустить важные сообщения
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)


# Хэндлер на команду /price
@dp.message_handler(commands=["price"])
async def priceb(message: types.Message):
    await message.answer(f"Цена биткоина = {await get_bitcoin_price()}")


@dp.message_handler(commands=["alert"])
async def alarm(message: types.Message):
    mean = int(message.text[6:])
    while True:
        await asyncio.sleep(3)
        if mean < await get_bitcoin_price():
            await message.answer(f"Цена биткоина пересекла вашу отметку {mean}")
            break


if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Запуск бота
    executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)
```

Comment: Спасибо большое помогло. А моя проверка это лишь малая часть задуманного

Comment: И разве можно сделать сохранению в базу числа? Всё равно же если выключать программу то значение которое сохранено в базу данных при повторном запуске не будет проверятся в алгоритме

Comment: Почему не будет? Алгоритм можно поделить на 2 части. Будет выглядеть примерно так: проверяем, есть ли в базе это число: если оно есть -> извлекаем его из базы и запускаем функцию, которая отслеживает цену битка. Если же числа нет -> юзер задает свое число -> сохраняем его в базу -> извлекаем его из базы и запускаем функцию, которая отслеживает цену битка. Когда бот будет снова перезапущен  - он уже будет работать по 1 части алгоритма, потому что число в базе есть. Но это просто как пример, вариантов может быть много